# How to restore the original size of this flash drive?

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, gparted, usb-drive

Using GParted:

[image]

This flash drive is a 1GB Kingston flash drive, in GParted it shows 8MB of space remaining, and when I try to create a partition table for it, it loads but nothing changes at all, so I can't create a partition for this disk.

I just want to use this flash drive normally for saving files, or maybe using Porteus, I just want to make this flash drive a normal one.

Comment: You used the menu option from __Device__ -> __Create partition table__?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a different utility (perhaps even on a different OS) to create the new partition table -- even command line `fdisk`.  If nothing else, you may get an informative error message.

It seems likely this drive has damaged hardware and is no longer writable; with the cost of new small thumb drives (almost free), it's surely not worth putting a lot of effort into recovering this one.